# MySQL trigger to update a field to the value of id

Tags: mysql, insert, triggers

I would like to have a trigger to perform following operation for inserted records:

```
 # pseudocode
 if new.group_id is null
    set new.group_id = new.id
 else
    # don't touch it
 end
```

More clearly: say I have one table with three columns: `id` primary key, `group_id` int, `value` varchar.

When I insert with `group_id` like that:

```
INSERT INTO table(value, group_id) VALUES ('a', 10)
```

I'd like to have:

```
id | group_id | value
---+----------+------
 1 |       10 | a
```

but when I omit `group_id`:

```
INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES ('b')
```

it should be automatically set to the `id` of this record:

```
id | group_id | value
---+----------+------
 2 |        2 | b
```

Is it possible with a trigger? (I know I can update the record after inserting but having the trigger would be nicer.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this in one statement, even using a trigger.

The trigger solution that @Lucky suggested would look like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.group_id = COALESCE(NEW.group_id, NEW.id);
END
```

However, there's a problem.  In the `BEFORE INSERT` phase, the auto-generated `id` value hasn't been generated yet.  So if `group_id` is null, it defaults to `NEW.id` which is always 0.

But if you change this trigger to fire during the `AFTER INSERT` phase, so you have access to the generated value of `NEW.id`, you can't modify column values.

MySQL doesn't support expressions for the `DEFAULT` of a column, so you can't declare this behavior in the table definition either. *Update: MySQL 8.0.13 supports `DEFAULT (<expression>)` but the expression still can't depend on an auto-increment value (this is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)).

The only solution is to do the `INSERT`, and then immediately do an `UPDATE` to change the `group_id` if it's not set.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (group_id, value) VALUES (NULL, 'a');
UPDATE MyTable SET group_id = COALESCE(group_id, id) WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: That sucks. Even in 2016

Comment: @AA_PV, this could be solved by an independent sequence object, like they do in Oracle. This has been an open feature request in MySQL since 2003: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1625 But in Oracle, to use the sequence, you *must* call it either in application code, which means writing code for *every* INSERT to a table you want to have an auto-inc primary key. Or else write a trigger for *every* such table. MySQL users enjoy being able to skip writing so many triggers, and just declare `AUTO_INCREMENT` as a column option instead.

Comment: yes but two AUTO_INCREMENT columns are not allowed in MySQL, right? Although I think something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7345183/4411645 can be done. And to avoid the nested query, maybe it can be maintained in the application code as well, though that might be even more unsafe, not sure.

Comment: @AA_PV, correct, two AUTO_INCREMENT columns are not supported. But most users find this is not a problem.

Comment: _In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated._ [Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) So you can use `OLD.id` to access the ID.

Comment: @ravo10, Please test that. I don't think `OLD.id` can be referenced in an INSERT trigger.

Comment: @BillKarwin Oh sorry. No, that is true! You can only use `OLD.id` for `DELETE` and `UPDATE`, but you need to use `NEW.id` for `INSERT`. I just made a system, and has been working fine until now.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `myTriggerNameHere`
BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.group_id = IF(NEW.group_id IS NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID()+1, NEW.group_id);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for multi-row insert as the LAST_INSERT_ID is not updated until the batch is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering here, as in the accepted answer [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485530/1384641) states:

> In the BEFORE INSERT phase, the auto-generated id value hasn't been
>   generated yet. So if group_id is null, it defaults to NEW.id which is
>   always 0.

---

I have an answer for it - for OP (and the visitors to come), here are few points:
You cannot update the table from where the trigger gets invoked, for it you'll get **Error 1442**:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'MyTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

**1.to Update the new row**
Use `BEFORE INSERT ON` trigger, this way you can update all the fields for the new row, which can be accessible via NEW operator i.e.

```
set NEW.group_id = NEW.id
```

**2.Get auto_increment value before insert**:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='MyTable'
```

To sum up  - the trigger SQL for 'd be something as following:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS MyTrigger//
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.group_id IS NULL
        set @auto_id := (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                         WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() ); 
        set NEW.group_id = @auto_id;
    ENF IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Selecting the auto_increment value from the table introduces a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

An old topic, but I've recently struggled with it. If you still interested, have you tried?:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `MyTable` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.group_id IS NULL OR LENGTH(NEW.group_id) = 0 THEN
            SET NEW.group_id = (SELECT MAX(id) +1 FROM MyTable ) ;
        END IF;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will work for you

I have two tables

```
test_b: a_id, value
test_c: a_id, value
```

And here is a trigger on the insert of test b. It checks to see if a_id is null and if it is it inserts 0

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_b AFTER INSERT ON test_b
  FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO test_c (a_id, value) VALUES (IFNULL(NEW.a_id, 0),NEW.value)
```

Comment: If you tell me more about the structure of your tables, I can modify this query to work for you.

Answer (score -3):

This trigger should do what you asked.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
          IF new.group_id IS NULL
            SET new.group_id = new.id
          END IF
      END;
```

It's copied from a very similar example in the [MYSQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) page.

Comment: Does not work on MySQL:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE new.group_id IS NULL END' at line 1

Comment: You should be able to get the exact syntax from the examples at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html - I didn't test. I'll try an edit

Comment: The NEW.id is not set and if group_id is unique, this will fail on the second row being inserted.

Answer (score -4):

A trigger seems like overkill in this situation. Simply apply a default.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `group_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you missed the point. It's not about inserting literal value `2` as `group_id`. I want the `id` of this record as the `group_id` unless I specify `group_id` explicitly.