# MySQL - Before Insert Trigger Syntax?

Tags: mysql, triggers

With MySQL 5.1.43.

I am trying to create a trigger like this:

```
USE `databaseA`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` trigger triggerName 
BEFORE INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF(convert(new.subTime, signed) > '600') THEN
SET new.fieldA = new.fieldB;
END IF;

END$$
```

When I insert a record the **fieldA** field does not update.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Can I use the **CONVERT** statement in the trigger?

Comment: This SO question has a similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211792/mysql-trigger-to-update-a-field-to-the-value-of-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your trigger and it works fine. Is there any error message? Also take a look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA -> TRIGGERS and check is your trigger defined properly.