# Get the id of current mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

is there anyway to get the ID of the current record I am **INSERTING** into the database table using php with Mysql without having to do an extra select to get the last ID?

FOr example, if my table has these columns, id, url, name 
and if url consists of the domain name and current id as the query variable ex:
domainname.com/page.php?id=current_id

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (id, url, name )
VALUES
('domainname.com/page.php?id=".**whats_the_current_id**."','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

Comment: What library/functions are you using to execute the insert? The answer depends on it... [and it's probably a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+last+insert+id).

Comment: I'm assuming you use PDO: [LastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: mysql_insert_id ?  http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: @Romain I'm assuming your assumption is an unlikely one

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but you could try: `INSERT INTO table SET url = CONCAT("http://beginning.of.the/url?id=", VALUES(id))`

Comment: i'm pretty sure your workflow has something weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use `mysql_insert_id()` for that. it works fine.

```
// pseudo-ish code
$query = "INSERT something .... "
$updated = $db->run_query($query);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 4):

as far as I know, there is no 'clean' way to find the ID you are about to insert (from what I understand from your question, this is what you want to know).

Two options in my opinion, starting with the ugly one: `select max(id) from Persons`, increment it with one, and hope that no insert's will mess this up for you. Like I said, its ugly, and -not- reliable.

A better option would be to first insert the record with a dummy value for url, and then retrieving the just inserted row's ID with `mysql_insert_id()`. Then update that record with the correct url value.

You asked for a way to retrieve the id without a select query following the insert query, but like I said, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I think it might be 'cleanly' possible with an insert trigger, not sure. Also, +1 for being the first answerer to actually understand the question.

Comment: Nice idea. I looked into the insert triggers a bit, but unfortunately for the question asker there is still a problem, which is explained quite well in the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211792/mysql-trigger-to-update-a-field-to-the-value-of-id). Saves the question asker the trouble of diving into triggers :)

Answer (score 1):

your table should be like this

```
ID AUTO_INCREMENT
person_id VARCHAR
person_url ...
person_name ...
```

your post form something like

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo uniqid() ?>" />
   ...
</form>
```

the query should be like this:

```
$person_id   = intval($_POST['id']);
$person_url  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
$person_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (person_id, persno_url, person_name) VALUES ( {$person_id} , {$person_url}, {$person_name} )");

$ID = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

The current ID is in `$_GET['id']`. You should sanitize it before inserting it into your query:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

Then, use `$id` in your query.

Answer (score -2):

If you add classes around the first insert and then the second select.  The select will work then.

```
<?php
class insert1{
     function inserthere(){
          ***insert***
     }
}
class select1{
     function selecthere(){
          ***select***
     }
}
$a = new insert1;
$a->inserthere();
$b = new select1;
$b->selecthere();
?>
```