# How to select the lastest record from a group in MySQL table using SQl syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the latest row of each group.

```
$SQL = "SELECT location_name, status, timecode FROM status_table WHERE location_name in ('G_01', 'J_01', 'M_01', 'A_01', 'U_01', 'W_01', 'W_1_01', 'C_01', 'G_2_01', 'M_01') GROUP BY location_name ORDER BY status";
```

The query only pull up the first row, and order by timecode does not work

Comment: in your sql query, ouy have put `ORDER BY status`. I think you should be `ORDER BY timecode`.

Comment: Do you have an id field (or any other field or combination of fields which can be used as a unique row identifier)? If so you should use a `GROUPWISE MAX` approach.

Comment: I tried order by timecode but it just orders the list by timecode still pulling the first row.

I have IDs for each status not for each group.

Comment: You should show us some data.

Comment: HStupid question maybe, but you do loop throughj your results right?

Comment: -Results
-J OFF  4:25 AM
-G OFF  1:45 PM
-M OFF  6:33 PM
-W2 OFF  10:25 PM
G_2 OFF  4:17 AM
Ma OFF  4:42 AM
A ON  7:41 PM
U ON  1:25 PM
W ON  6:25 PM
C ON  4:20 AM


1  Jabi_01  OFF  2013-09-08 04:25:13
2  Gwarinpa_01  OFF  2013-09-08 13:45:19
3  Maitama_01  OFF  2013-09-08 18:33:33
etc

Comment: Do you have an auto incrementing id column or not?

Comment: I do have an auto incrementing id

Comment: Think my answer below should work if i remember my GROUPWISE MAX stuff correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an auto incrementing `id` column:

```
SELECT location_name, status, timecode FROM status_table WHERE id IN(
   SELECT MAX(id) FROM status_table WHERE location_name in ('G_01', 'J_01', 'M_01', 'A_01', 'U_01', 'W_01', 'W_1_01', 'C_01', 'G_2_01', 'M_01') GROUP BY location_name
) ORDER BY status
```

Should work by getting the MAX id for each "group" (location name) then get the details for that id, and finally order the resultset by status

Answer (score 0):

It will only pull the first row because the group by is only on one column.

Try including your other selected fields in the GROUP BY clause

```
$SQL = "SELECT location_name, status, timecode FROM status_table 
WHERE location_name in  
('G_01', 'J_01', 'M_01', 'A_01', 'U_01', 'W_01', 'W_1_01', 'C_01', 'G_2_01', 'M_01') 
GROUP BY location_name, status, timecode 
ORDER BY status";
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant get you properly but till i understand i think below links really help you

1) **[php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)**
2)**[Get the id of current mysql insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658080/get-the-id-of-current-mysql-insert)**
3)**[MySQL - Select the last inserted row easiest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770600/mysql-select-the-last-inserted-row-easiest-way)**
4)**[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)**

i hope above links are helpful....