# Autoincrement in mysql without unique ids

Tags: mysql

I have a table with main-ids and user-ids. Each user-id has a set of their own unique main-ids, but multiple user-ids can have the same main-id. Is there anyway to increment a main-id for a specific user without having to do 2 queries?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'increment a `main-id` for a specific user '. Isn't the `main-id` a foreign key into the `main-ids` table? Can you provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE main_ids` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_ids`?

Comment: The user-id is actually the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean like this:

```
User ID       Main ID
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             1
2             2
2             3
```

Then you're going to need to make an INSERT trigger that finds the next MainID for that user and stores that.

Comment: that's exactly the structure. Would you be able to guide me on what the trigger would look like?

Comment: OK, to find the next mainid, you would `select max(mainid) from my_table where user_id = ?` and increment it.  Then use that to set the mainid on the current row.  Check out [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211792/mysql-trigger-to-update-a-field-to-the-value-of-id) which talks about having to do it as an AFTER trigger.  Also, watch out for locking (concurrency) issues, and also what happens on UPDATE/DELETE.  Good luck.